# How to turn to 0 the specific bit of number in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, I have a number 255 that is 1111 1111 in binary form. I want to turn the first bit to 0 and get the 0111 1111 (127). What is the easiest way to do this? How I can change the bits of number directly?

Comment: The more generic question and solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173774/modify-bits-in-an-integer-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = 0b11111111    # = 255
mask = 0b01111111 # = 127

res = a & mask
print('{0} {0:08b}'.format(res))
# -> 127 01111111
```

Comment: I got the idea. Thank you!

Comment: Accept the answer then :)

Comment: Is the first zero, before `b`, related to the sign?

Comment: you mean the leading zero in the formatting string `08b`? that will just zero-fill the resulting string if the bitlength is shorter than 8. `'{0:03b}'.format(0) = 000`.