# How to bitshift in Python to manipulate a filesystem octal

Tags: python, octal

I have an octal representing Linux file permissions. 
The permissions are currently, I.E `0o640` and I want to set the group bit to 6 (so `0o660`). I saw that I can set the bit in the nth place [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173774/how-to-modify-bits-in-an-integer) but the results I get are peculiar, I guess that it is because of the octal representation.

I Tried:

```
perm = 0o640
# Set the bit in the 2nd place (index 1) to 6. 
new_perm = perm | (6<<1)
# new_perm is now 0o634 (wanted 0o660).
```

I'm doing something wrong I guess...

I also wonder what is the advantage of using octal instead of regular integers in Python when working with file permissions.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a Unix tradition to use Octal representation - some argue that it's simple to read: https://www.quora.com/Why-do-nix-systems-use-the-octal-number-system-for-representing-file-directory-permissions-Why-is-it-helpful.
In Python, there's a number of file perm contestants you can use to easily set perms using `os.chmod`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249440/changing-file-permission-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<<` shift number by a bit. for the answer you want you should shift `0o600` by `3`.

```py
perm = 0o600
new_perm = (perm  & 0o707) | (6<<3)
print(new_perm == 0o660) # True
```

---

According to comment we should first make the bits we want to zero and then use `|`.

`(perm & 0o707)` This part of code make that happens.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why 3?

Comment: Because an each octal number is 3 bits  number for example `0o6` equals with `0b110`.

Comment: @GalShahar note that this doesn't work with other parameters, as `|` always "turns on" bits. to actualy overwrite the entire octal digit you first need to 0 it and then use `|` to set the bits you want on.

Comment: @GalShahar Yes, you're right, in this case those digits was 0, but we want to work with any perm we should make them to `0`.